Chrome is ignoring my attempts to unset cookies (Django)
I'm trying to unset my cookie on an https site. The cookie was set by the server after successful login but chrome is not unsetting the cookie when logout is called even though the Set-Cookie header is present on the response headers with the correct directives.
@api_view(['POST'])
def login(request):
    data = request.data
    email = data.get('email')
    password = data.get('password')
    
    if not email or not password:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Email and password are required'}, status=400)
    
    user = authenticate_user(email, password)
    
    if user is not None:
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        # Create response object
        response = JsonResponse({'message': 'Login successful'})
        
        # Set the token in a secure, HTTP-only cookie
        response.set_cookie(
            key='access_token',
            value=str(token.access_token),
            httponly=True,
            secure=True,  # Ensure you use HTTPS
            samesite='Lax',
            path='/',
            domain='my-domain.com'
        )
        
        return response
    else:
        # Authentication failed
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=401)

This is my logout method:
@api_view(['POST'])
def logout(request):
    # Create response object
    response = JsonResponse({'message': 'Logout successful'})
    
    response.set_cookie(
        'access_token',
        value='',
        max_age=0,
        path='/',
        secure=True,
        httponly=True,
        samesite='Lax',
        domain='my-domain.com'
    )
    
    return response

Additionally I have the following in my settings.py file:
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'my-domain.com'
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'my-domain.com'

This is what my client side request looks like, I'm using Redux. The request succeeds.
const protectConfig = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  withCredentials: true
};

export const logout = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch(setAlert('Logged Out Successfully', 'success'));
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + API_LOGOUT,
      protectConfig
    );
    dispatch({
      type: LOGOUT,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(setAlert(err.response.data.detail, 'error'));
    dispatch({
      type: LOGOUT_FAIL,
    });
  }
};

I've tested on Firefox and also in incognito mode. What could possibly be causing the cookies not to be unset by my logout method?

Why not response.delete_cookie('access_token')?

Did you check in the devtools or on an API request whether the cookies were actually still there? It looks to me like that cookie is some sort of JWT access token, if so removing that cookie won't really make the token invalid if that's what you're trying to do. Please [edit] and clarify how you are validating whether that cookie is removed or not.

@willeM_VanOnsem response.delete_cookie wasn't working either, which is why I resorted to setting the cookie again with a max_age of 0

@AbdulAzizBarkat I'm checking using the dev tools yes, when I logout the cookie is still there and I can still access my servers resources if I manually navigate to my-domain.com/a-protected-resource
I'm now also calling the logout(request) method from django.contrib.auth in my logout function

@Warwick delete_cookie works the same way you're trying to do it, it uses set_cookie and sets a max-age of 0 and an expiry in the past.

@AbdulAzizBarkat ok, but I don't understand why chrome ignores it, when I use delete_cookie I can see the Set-Cookie header is also there, but it has no effect

Ah, wait, you've tagged this with React JS, do you have a separate frontend from your backend? Please share the frontend code that is making requests to these two endpoints then so that we have a proper [mre] (Cookies work a bit differently if you're using AJAX)

@AbdulAzizBarkat I've added the client side request code to my submission above, I'm using axios

You can't set or send samesite='Lax' cookies in a cross-site request. See: CORS requests are not contains the samesite cookies

@AbdulAzizBarkat setting samesite='None' has unfortunately not resolved the issue

I managed to get it working. I was calling my redux login function in a React handler which wasn't using async await which might have been causing issues with the application of the Set-Cookie header. Furthermore I want to thank @AbdulAzizBarkat for pointing out the samesite='None' config required for cross-site requests.
